# Contact Record Limits

Tags: data-loader, governorlimits

We are working on a new implementation and have 5 million contacts in our existing database.  What do I need to consider before migrating those over?  I do not plan to use much salesforce reporting.
We have procured 50GB of additional data storage.
Can a contact be a big-object?  If I'm out of luck what strategy can I use to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

No, Contact cannot be a Big Object, but it doesn't need to be. 5 million records is not even particularly large as large Salesforce databases go. I've worked on orgs that are an order of magnitude larger.

You will definitely want to use the Bulk API (probably through a data loader product, although of course you can write your own scripts to talk to the API if you prefer) to load these records, which will allow you to load them at reasonable speed. The Bulk API is the right tool for any large-volume data load.

As a side note, you'll want to think early about your strategy for preserving any relationships in your existing data, whether that is done using External Id fields in Salesforce or through logic in your data migration scripts.

---

You raised reporting as a concern. You may get value out of reading [Best Practices for Deployments with Large Data Volumes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_best_practices.htm). It lays out a lot of detail around how to manage large data volume in Salesforce, where performance concerns will be an issue, and what strategies you can use to counter those risks.

You shouldn't write off reporting! An effective strategy in using selective, indexed filters can most certainly yield good, performant reports on a 5 million record data set, but you will need to be proactive in planning that strategy for the best outcome and to avoid frustration when reports time out on you and your users.

Comment: thank you for the response.  What would be a "number" for Custom Objects that would require a big object.  We have 1 table that has 23 million?

Comment: Big Objects are a situation-specific tool that you use when you're willing to accept its limitations. Data volume alone is _not_ a specific recommendation of Big Objects, which come with substantial limitations on how you can interact with the records. 23 million records is not too large for a Custom Object to be used effectively given the planning and strategy I linked too above.

Comment: Considering that you're migrating what sounds like several tens of millions of records into Salesforce, you'd probably really benefit from having an architect with LDV experience advise your project. At that scale you really do need to pre-plan some aspects of your implementation to get a satisfactory outcome.

Comment: Thanks very much for that.